# Easiest way to scale an equation

Tags: linear-algebra

I have an equation `x = -(1/abs(y))` that creates a 2D profile of a shape. That profile is then imported into a CAD package and stuff happens. I could use a scale command inside the CAD package but this would introduce error due to how the CAD package approximates the curve. I think I really want to scale the equation and let the CAD package approximate the scaled profile.

I tried adding a scale factor of 2 by changing the equation to `x = -((1/abs(y))*2)`. It seems correct but my algebra is a little rusty. Any thoughts on my approach or the best approach to handle this?

Comment: You need to say more about how you desire to re-scale. For example do you want to doube both the $x$ and $y$ values of your original curve? [If so, and original curve is $y=f(x)$ then the re-scale woultd be the function $y=2f(x/2).$ othr multiples than $2$ would be $y=kf(x/k)$ where $k$ is the multiplier. Or do you want to rescale only the $x$ values, or only the $y$ values?

Comment: @coffeemath - I might be missing something basic. Those rusty algebra skills and I've moved on to other things since college.  In this equation, X depends on the value of Y so doesn't a multiplier effectively scale the X and Y? I do want to scale in the X and Y axes. For starters, I want to scale the curve three times `x = -((1/abs(y))*3)` and then, based on some other factors, I'll adjust from there.

Comment: What I mean is this. Suppose you have a graph of your starting function. So in function notation, if your function is $f,$ then the graph is the set of points $(a,b)=(x,f(x)).$ I'm asking starting from a point $(a,b)$ on the original graph, what point do you want to be on the new graph? Is it $(ka,kb)$ or $(a,kb)$ or $(ka,b)$ or some other choice? [where $k$ is your "scale factor"]

Comment: @coffeemath - Ah, okay. It really doesn't matter because I can move the curve in CAD since moving doesn't cause the same issues as scaling. Thinking about it briefly, I think the starting point should scale relative to the origin (0,0) using the same scale factor. FYI, I'm considering adding an offset value to shift the curve to the right (+X) to potentially eliminate the need to move in CAD and enable curves to be created via script but that's a low priority.